# 'com.westernacher.xna.template.boot.AuthenticationProperties' is deprecated and marked for removal

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Due to upgradation of SpringBoot v2.7.3 to v3.1.1, facing deprecation issue of AuthenticationProperties class.

Import code line:

import com.westernacher.xna.template.boot.AuthenticationProperties;

What is the replacement for AuthenticationProperties?

Comment: have you checked the documentation for that class? It's quite likely to be mentioned there

Comment: Yes but couldn't find any - https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.1-SNAPSHOT/migration/index.html Please share the link if I'm checking wrong one.

Comment: why are you looking at the documentation of 6.1-SNAPSHOT, to answer a question about 3.1.1?